# Sqldatareader invalid cast exception getDouble

Tags: c#, mysql, cast

Estoy intentando obtener valores de tipo Double desde un datareader sql, hasta ahí todo bien, pasa que cuando hago un dr.getDouble(2) me da invalid cast exception.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Byte[]' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'.'

Hago una consulta mysql sería algo del estilo:

```
Select str1, 'un alias cualquiera', count(*)
from tabla
where valor > 30 and str1 like('Algo')
group by str1
union
Select str1, 'un alias cualquiera', count(*)
from tabla
where valor > 40 and str1 like('Algo')
group by str1
union
...
```

Tabla de valores

```
+-----------+--------------+---------+
| String    |  Alias       |  1.92   |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
| String    |  Alias       |  98     |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
| String    |  Alias       | 43.23   |
+-----------+--------------+---------+
```

Esto es lo que yo intento en mi código.

```
MySqlConnection conn = null;
MySqlCommand consulta = null;
MySqlDataReader dr;
Double val;

inicializarconexion(conn, consulta); //hasta aquí ningún problema.

val = dr.getDouble(2);  //Aquí salta la excepción.
```

Captura de el count(*)

[image: Count]

Comment: De que tipo es esa columna en la base de datos? O esa columna es el `count(*)`?

Comment: Mira mi última edición, quise poner algo sencillo pero me di cuenta de que lo había puesto mal para el ejemplo, la última columna es un count(*)

Comment: Si es `Count(*)`, debes usar `GetInt32`, no `GetDouble`

Comment: ¿Aunque el count devuelva un número con decimales?

Comment: Como va a devolver un `count` un número con decimales? creo que no estas haciendo bien la consulta para empezar. Que es lo que quieres obtener en esa columna?

Comment: Dame un momento, subo una captura.

Comment: @Pikoh ya subí la captura

Comment: Puedes poner la consulta? `Count(*)` cuenta **filas**, no puede dar decimales

Comment: Dame un momentito, edito y la ajusto un poco más a la realidad.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71706/discussion-between-aritzbn-and-pikoh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo.

El problema estaba en que en las consultas count(*) estaba como alias, dentro de este había unos cuantos avg para sacar media, de ahí los decimales.

Solución:

```
Byte[] val;            
val = (Byte[])dr.GetValue(2);
stat.setValor(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(val));
```

Para pasar después de  String  a double. (Aunque suene enrevesado)

```
Double.Parse(val,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```